# Supervised training and testing in GenSims FastText implementation

Tags: machine-learning, text, classification, gensim, fasttext

I am currently training a Gensim FastText model with a document from a certain domain with the unsupervised training method from Gensim.

After this training of the word representations i would like to train a set of sentence+label lines and ultimately test the model and return a precision and recall value like it is possible in facebooks fastText implementation via train_supervised + test. Does GenSims implementation support the supervised training and testing? I couldnt get it to work / find the required methods.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gensim's `FastText` implementation has so far chosen not to support the same `supervised` mode of Facebook's original FastText, where known-labels can be used to drive the training of word-vectors – because `gensim` sees it focus as being unsupervised topic-modeling techniques.